# Send Netscape Cookie with Python

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, pycurl

How can i load Netscape cookie from a file to auth to a website REST API 
with python requests[session], pycurl or something else ? 
Similar to curl -b ${home}.cookie

> -b, --cookie  (HTTP) Pass the data to the HTTP server as a cookie. It is supposedly the data previously received from the server
>   in a "Set-Cookie:" line.  The data should  be in the format
>   "NAME1=VALUE1; NAME2=VALUE2".

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

proxi = {'http': 'http://proxy',
         'https': 'http://proxy'}

url = 'http://192.196.1.98:8080/a/changes/?q=status:new' 
r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxi) #cookies=cookie

print r.status_code
print r.json()
print r.headers
print r.request.headers
print r.text
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure people refer to them as "HTTP cookies" or simply "cookies" in this century.

Comment: What i meant by Netscape cookie is: "The netscape cookie file format stores one cookie per physical line in the file with a bunch of associated meta data, each field separated with TAB. That file is called the cookiejar in curl terminology."  Not {key:value} format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Python request library quick start guide](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies) has a section on cookies. It details a class for holding cookies called `RequestsCookieJar`, which you need to load the cookies into by parsing the Netscape cookie file manually.

```py
import requests

# Open cookie file
cookies_txt = open(r"cookies.txt")

# Initialize RequestsCookieJar
jar = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()

for line in cookies_txt.readlines():
    words = line.split()

    # Filter out lines that don't contain cookies
    if (len(words) == 7) and (words[0] != "#"):
        # Split cookies into the appropriate parameters
        jar.set(words[5], words[6], domain=words[0], path=words[2])

# Make the request
url = "https://website.com"
website = requests.get(url, proxy=proxi, cookies=jar)
```